# MS word auto numbering restart at 1 won't work

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have put an example document [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37884381/Doc1.docx)
I can't get the line number of Algorithm 1 to restart at 1.

I know the following work around may work:

1. If I keep all Algorithm code in one text box, but obviously I don't
   want to do that.
2. if I manually enter the line number
3. if I use latex from now on ...

But I'd like to know if there is an elegant solution for my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure why it occurred, I think there is corruption of some kind with the Code style. I noticed that when you click on the auto numbers themselves only 2-5 is highlighted for Algorithm 2 and 4.  So what I did was highlighted line one of Algorithm 2, clicked on the format painter, dragged the painter over each line of Algorithm 1, and then restarted the numbering at 1 for Algorithm 2.  It fixed the numbering ([here's the doc](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62470407/Doc1%20%281%29.docx)).

Comment: Amazing! but I couldn't reproduce your fix.. [here is another doc](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37884381/Doc2.docx) I tried:click on Algo 1 line 1 -> format painter -> click on Algo 2 line 1 -> restart the numbering at 1, didn't work

Comment: Whatever you copied from caused conflicts with your Normal.dot. I had that problem a while back with using a style that had outline numbering.  There were so many conflicts with similar styles and that royally screwed up the numbering. What I did was create a clean document template based on a clean normal.dot, eliminated all unnecessary styles, and make changes directly to the document.  In your case, there seems to be something going on with the text boxes. Were they pasted in from elsewhere? I swapped out code and used list number instead, same error.

Comment: I created a template for you with the correct numbering. Use that every time you work with that numbering style: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62470407/Code%20Template.dotx

Comment: I downloaded the template file you provided, but the Algorithm 2 still starts from 2? I want every Algorithm to start with line 1

Comment: You'll need to verify that normal.dot is corrupt. To do that, rename your normal.dot file to "oldnormal" or something similar in the event you want to transfer styles. Word will automatically create a new default version of normal.dot when you start Word. The numbering should work correctly after that.